# Cascading Dropdown using JQuery/AJAX return undefined results even though I can see the array

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a JQuery Script that has an event listener added to a dropdown. I am also making an AJAX call to a handler. I am trying to populate another dropdown  that is returned from the getJSON call.

```
    <script>
        $(function () {
            debugger;
        $("#bid").on("change", function () {
            var budgetId = $(this).val();
            $("#SuiteId").empty();
            $("#SuiteId").append("<option value=''>--- Select Suite Number ---</option>");
            $.getJSON(`?handler=SuiteId&budgetId=${budgetId}`, (data) => {
                $.each(data, function (i,item) {
                    $("#SuiteId").append(`<option value="${item.suiteId}">${item.suiteNo}</option>`);
                    return (i !== "result")
                });
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
}
```

The problem I have is with how my data is returning. For example: item = Array(3)

Here are the contents of my array

```
{suiteId: 123 suiteNo: "001"}
{suiteId: 456 suiteNo: "002"}
{suiteId: 789 suiteNo: "003"}
```

Instead my append method returns "undefined". Can anyone offer advice? Am i appending incorrectly? I'd like it to display based on the apprend method I have below.

**Additional Note**
Removing .suiteId and .suiteNo yields my dropdown results like this

```
--- Select Suite Number ---
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove `.suiteId` from `item` and you get  `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]` in option it means your `item` is still an array and you are not looping your `data` correctly, and is also reason behind `undefined`.

Because you did not post your exact `data` format you are getting as response in order for us to see exact structure you can as fast fix add another loop:

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
  item.forEach(opt => {
    $("#SuiteId").append(`<option value="${opt.suiteId}">${opt.suiteNo}</option>`);
    return (i !== "result")
  })
});
```

and once again I am saying you have one for each to many, you need just one, but we need to see exact output not just contents of `data`.